# Can I delete a file file from _restore-{uid} folder?

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

I installed a password cracker and my virusscan triggered alerts for it. So I uninstalled it, but now the scanner triggers alerts for its presence in _restore folder.

If I let the virusscan delete the files, would it affect restorability of the system? In past System Restore has failed for unknown reasons so I know it is somewhat fragile.

Comment: @Moab your comment is confusing since it came before Randolph's answer

Comment: No, I deleted my comment. Now these comments need moderator attention :-)

Comment: @HemalPandya his answer was not showing when I posted, only his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will affect it. Just like Microsoft and all the big antivirus vendors recommend, you need to completely remove your System Restore points to eliminate an infection.

This would be the same case here. Turn it off, then turn it on again, bearing in mind that you'll lose your old restore points.

Comment: Well I guess I will have to live with the virus warning :)